# Pytorch-How to test/fine-tune a model using a new data type with different arithmetics for basic operations (+,-,/,*) compared to float?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, data-representation

I want to use a new data representation instead of float for fine-tuning/testing a model (e.g., DNN) in Pytorch. The basic arithmetic operations (add/sub/multiply/division) in my data type is different from floating point. Is it possible to implement these basic operations and force all of functions in Pytorch (e.g., torch.add(), torch.sum(), torch.nn.Linear(), conv2d, etc.) to use this new implementation for basic arithmetic? If so, could you please guide me on how to do this?

Because I think otherwise it takes so much time and effort to first find which functions my model calls (which I dont know how to do it) and, then, I have to replace them one by one. This becomes complicated for a large model.

Thank you!

I found this link from Pytorch that shows how to extend pytorch. But it seems that it is not comprehensive enough to answer my question.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html

Answer (score 0):

To test or fine-tune a PyTorch model using a new data type with different arithmetic rules for basic operations, you need to define a custom data type by creating a new PyTorch tensor type. This process involves defining custom operations and ensuring that the new data type adheres to the expected behavior during various tensor operations.

Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow:

1. Define the Custom Data Type
2. Register the Custom Data Type
3. Implement the Operations
4. Fine-tune or Test the Model

Here's a simple code:

```
import torch

class Modulo10Tensor(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        output = input % 10
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = grad_output.clone()
        return grad_input

# Register the custom data type
torch.Tensor.register_hook('modulo10')(Modulo10Tensor.apply)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a model using the custom data type
    model = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1).to('modulo10')

    # Generate sample input data
    input_data = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], requires_grad=True).to('modulo10')

    # Forward pass using the custom data type
    output = model(input_data)

    print(output)  # Output will be modulo 10

    # Perform backward pass to update gradients
    loss = output.sum()
    loss.backward()

    # Check gradients
    print(input_data.grad)
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer! I am actually trying to replicate LNS-Madam paper that is using a logarithmic number system. Hence, I need to implement all the arithmetic operations in LNS format. For example, multiplications turn to addition and addition itself will be more like a lookup table. Could you please give an example of how to do step 3 (Implement the Operations)?

Comment: Also in your code, "model = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1).to('modulo10')", does this to('modulo10') force Linear function (a high level function) to use the new arithmetic operations for all the sub-operations (add and mul) in the Linear? or we need to check Linear implementation and manually replace the lower level operations with our new functions defined for LNS?

Comment: sorry for the no response. been busy. do you still need help with this? if yes, I will try to provide an answer by end of day.